# fullcalendar.js, cannot navigate through periods

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.js for the first time, I implemented it successfully, I managed to retrieve and display my events, and I'm now working on the design of my calendar.

However, my calendar started to act weird, and now, for instance, I cannot navigate through weeks after I've loaded my page, the only way, I can is by changing the calendar view, by clicking month or day view button, then I'll be able to navigate and go back to week view to navigate through weeks. This happens regardless of the default view (if it's month view, I won't be able to go to next or previous months without changing the selected view first), the dates in the header change, but the content doesn't.

As it has worked previously, I tried to restart with simpler code (I tried to initialize my calendar with only the licence key, and as I was working on the design, I removed all the css), I get no error in the browser console, I tried with both Firefox and Chrome, I also wiped browser cache, but it hadn't improved anything.

I'm quite sure there's nothing to do with my ajax call (worked fine with it before, now doesn't work even without it) so I don't provide my controller code.

I'm using fullcalendar.3.9.0.

Here is my js (not in $(document).ready() but I tried and it did not change anything) :

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        bootstrapFontAwesome: {
            close: 'fa-times',
            prev: 'fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa-chevron-right',
            prevYear: 'fa-angle-double-left',
            nextYear: 'fa-angle-double-right'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        firstDay: 1,
        allDaySlot: false,
        editable: false,
        droppable: false,
        columnFormat: 'ddd DD/MM',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        nowIndicator: true,
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            Post('/Incident/GetInterventionList',
                {
                    start: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    end: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                },
                function (response) {
                    var events = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        let e = response[i];
                        events.push({
                            id: e.ActivityId,
                            title: e.SANumber + " | " + e.Subject,
                            start: moment(e.MorningStart ? e.MorningStart : e.EveningStart).toISOString(),
                            end: moment(e.EveningEnd ? e.EveningEnd : e.MorningEnd).toISOString(),
                            color: (e.StateCode == 0 ? '#ffc107' : (e.StateCode == 1 ? '#28a745' : (e.StateCode == 3 ? '#dc3545' : '#007bff')))
                        });
                    }

                    callback(events);
                });
        }
    });
```

And here is my css (I'm using bootstrap.sass) :

```
table {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/ /* blocks event display in fullCalendar */
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
}

table td, th {
    border: none !important;
}

table thead {
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 0 !important;
}

table thead th:first-child, table thead th:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0 !important;
}

table thead th:last-child, table thead th:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0.25rem 0 0 !important;
}

table tfoot {
    border-radius: 0 0 0.25rem 0.25rem !important;
}

table tfoot td {
    min-height: 9px;
}

table tfoot tr:last-child td:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0.25rem !important;
}

table tfoot tr:last-child td:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.25rem 0 !important;
}

.fc-scroller {
    max-height: 60vh;
    height: 60vh !important;
}

#calendar .btn {
    margin:3px;
}

.fc-event {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px black;
}

table table {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}

table tfoot td {
    height: 9px;
}

.fc-row {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Thanks for reading, help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Demo (your code, but with some static events instead of the ajax): http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/9/ shows no problem as far as I can see. I think your problem is not in the code you've shown us, unfortunately, unless it's the AJAX which is causing some sort of problem, despite your claim in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I've already tried (and just tried again just to be sure) without the ajax call, with and without static events, but unfortunately it still doesn't work, I'm probably missing something but I don't know what yet.

Comment: That's quite strange. The only thing I can suggest is to try removing options and features from the code until it starts working again. Start with obviously custom things like your CSS, and the bootstrap theme (and of course remove the bootstrap JS and CSS files as well), then try removing the Scheduler add-on, and then remove options from the fullCalendar one by one until you have the most basic setup. Hopefully that will reveal something. If it still doesn't work, then maybe you have something else in your page interfering. I can't really help more than that, I'm afraid.

Comment: I found what's the source of the problem, even changing the fullCalendar version, or installing JQuery.fullCalendar instead didn't helped. But you were right, as simple as my page was, something was silently interfering with fullCalendar, I was adding a `<tfoot>` tag at the bottom of my calendar in my `$(document).ready()` function, simply removing this resolved my problem. Thanks for your help @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this could help, the issue wasn't in the code provided here, actually there were something silently interfering with fullCalendar in my code (as suggested @ADyson, see comments), I was modifying the fullCalendar main table (dynamically adding a `<tfoot>` tag) after pageload and this was the source of the problem.